# Is there analogue for microdata's "content" attribute in microformats?

Tags: html, microdata, microformats

Recently first time I had to use microformats and microdata and met following problem. 
I need to display currency not in ISO-format. As I understood in microdata I could provide actual value in "content" attribute:

```
<span itemprop="price">123</span> <span itemprop="currency" content="RUB">руб.</span>
```

In microformats if I do like that:

```
<span class="price">123 руб.</span>
```

I'm getting "Price field includes invalid characters" warning in Google structured data testing tool

If like that:

```
<span class="price">123</span> <span class="currency">руб.</span>
```

then "Currency should be in ISO 4217 format" warning.

How can I do it in microformats? Do I have to worry about all these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't do `<span itemprop="currency" content="RUB">руб.</span>` in microdata. The `content` attribute is only valid on a meta element. So you could do `<meta itemprop="currency" content="RUB">руб.`. Unlike normal `<meta>` elements, these can appear in the `<body>` section of the page. However, there's no direct microformat equivalent of this.

But you could also do `<data itemprop="currency" value="RUB">руб.</data>` to achieve the same thing in microdata, and it seems that the similar `<data class="currency" value="RUB">руб.</data>` will do the same job in microformats - see http://microformats.org/#time-data - at least in principle, since it's still quite new.

Failing that, I believe that the old way of doing this in microformats was `<abbr class="currency" title="RUB">руб.</abbr>` but this is horrible semantics and I would heavily discourage it.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Variant with "data" tag unfortunately gives the same "Currency should be in ISO 4217 format" warning. But variant with "title" attribute works

Comment: The `content` attribute on the `span` element is invalid HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088904/html5-microdata-span-content/27089168#27089168

Comment: @RicardoGladwell - I appreciate you leaving a comment, but that's what the first two sentences of the answer says.