# HTML5 microdata: span content?

Tags: html, microdata

I have read [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/single-page.html), [the microdata specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/), and [the WHATWG HTML5 (with microdata) specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/). These are well written and easy to understand.

But now I read the [schema.org Book specification](http://schema.org/Book), and came across snippets like the following:

```
<span itemprop="price" content="6.99">$6.99</span>
<span itemprop="inLanguage" content="en">English-language</span>
<span itemprop="name" content="Tolkien, J. R. R. (John Ronald Reuel)">
  J. R. R. Tolkien</span>
```

Apparently (compare with the JSON version), the values of these microdata properties are the values of the `content` attributes of the `span` elements. (Of course, if there is no `content` attribute, the value is instead the `textContents` of the `span` element.)

But I cannot find any support for this practice in the HTML and microdata specifications. In fact, I cannot even find any evidence that there is a `content` attribute on `span` elements at all!

- The microdata specification doesn't say anything about a `span` `content` attribute when it gives the rules for [values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values). [Unless 'the element's textContent' is overridden by the `content` attribute, but I cannot find any support for this either.]
- Not even the full WHATWG HTML5+microdata specification supports the claim that there is a `content` attribute on `span` (see [The `span` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-span-element) and [Global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#global-attributes)).

So, I suppose the schema.org example is non-conforming. But is it also plain wrong? If not, where does this practice come from, and how accepted is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is wrong. Neither Microdata nor HTML5 define a `content` attribute for the `span` element.

Several people wanted to use it, see for example the code in these questions:

- [Hide Microdata property value in 'content' attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873095/hide-microdata-property-value-in-content-attribute)
- [Categories for Product in schema.org?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031818/categories-for-product-in-schema-org)
- [Is the "content" attribute valid for the <span> tag > if so is it a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134818/is-the-content-attribute-valid-for-the-span-tag-if-so-is-it-a-good-practic)
- [schema.org product availability tags markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148439/schema-org-product-availability-tags-markup)

I’m not sure where exactly this confusion is coming from.

(It doesn’t help that Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool incorrectly uses the `content` attribute instead of the element content; but at least all [other Microdata parsers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/online-microdata-parser) seem to do it correctly.)

Maybe some people got confused because RDFa (but not Microdata) defines and allows the [`content` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-rdfa-core-20130822/#A-content) for `span`. See HTML+RDFa’s [Extensions to the HTML5 Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax):

> For the avoidance of doubt, the following RDFa attributes are allowed on all elements in the HTML5 content model: `@vocab`, `@typeof`, `@property`, `@resource`, `@prefix`, `@content`, `@about`, `@rel`, `@rev`, `@datatype`, and `@inlist`.

Comment: I filed an [issue](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/184) about this Schema.org example.

Comment: "Plus one" for information on parser behaviour and the RDFa confusion origin hypothesis.

Comment: This documentation example does show an `@content` attribute with a `<span>` tag, despite the current standard: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146898 . Is there no solution for this in (other) microdata (parsers)?

Comment: To reiterate the answer above with a link to the syntax spec, `@content` does not have these restrictions in RDFa: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#A-content


"""If some displayed text is different from the actual 'value' it represents, a more precise value can be added using `@content`. A value can also optionally be typed using `@datatype`"""

Answer (score 3):

*(Sorry, I didn't have enough reputation to post a comment.)*

We're at the end of 2017 now. Somehow, the MDN webdocs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop)
and the schema docs (http://schema.org/telephone) still propose to use a `content` attribute on `span` using microdata. No html5 validator will accept this of course.