# Extending schema microdata property

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata

I've pondering over the best way to do this for quite some time now. We have a product, which is marked up by the normal `Product` properties along with an `Offer` for price, availability and such. However, the shop can sell the same item as either new or used (at two different prices), and I'm not entirely sure how I can go about marking the used price up.

In terms of actual HTML, the only way the "used" version exist, is as a "buy as used" link, so I can't mark it up as two different items (which would also be wrong as it is the same item with the same URL and ID. The only difference in terms of buying it is which warehouse we pick it from).

The markup is roughly:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="name">Fifa</span>
    <span itemprop="manufacturer">EA</span>
    <div itemprop="offer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
         <a href="#">Buy at <span itemprop="price" content="30">30</span>$</a>
         <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
         <a href="#">Buy used at <span>25</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to mark the used price span with `<span itemprop="price/used">`, however, I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way to do it (Rich Snippet tool gives me an error, but I don't actually know if the tool accepts custom properties or it just marks them as false), but as far as I can read from the [documentation](http://schema.org/docs/extension.html) it should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different offers for the product, so you should have two `Offer` items.

You can specify the condition with the [`itemCondition`](http://schema.org/itemCondition) property and its values [`NewCondition`](http://schema.org/NewCondition) / [`UsedCondition`](http://schema.org/UsedCondition).

Taking your snippet, it could look like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="name">Fifa</span>
    <span itemprop="manufacturer">EA</span>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <a href="#">Buy at <span itemprop="price">30</span>$</a>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
    </div>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
      <a href="#">Buy used at <span itemprop="price">25</span>$</a>
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/UsedCondition" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Side notes:

- The property is [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers), not `offer`.
- The [`span` element can’t have a `content` attribute in Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669).