# "missing required attribute href" and "itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item"

Tags: html, w3c-validation, microdata, rdfa

I'm trying to add structured data snippets. But it is showing some errors in W3C validation. Website address: www.truewayfze.com

> Error Line 14, Column 73: Element link is missing required attribute href.
>
> ```
> <link itemprop="image" content="http://www.truewayfze.com/img/logo.png"/>
> ```
>
> Error Line 16, Column 83: Element link is missing required attribute href.
>
> ```
> …k property="og:image" content="http://www.truewayfze.com/img/products/2.jpg" />
> ```
>
> Error Line 14, Column 73: The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.
>
> ```
> <link itemprop="image" content="http://www.truewayfze.com/img/logo.png"/>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Your first error:

The `link` element [can’t have a `content` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) in HTML5+Microdata. You probably want to use the `href` attribute instead:

```html
<link itemprop="image" href="http://www.truewayfze.com/img/logo.png" />
```

Your second error:

The `link` element could have a `content` attribute in HTML5+RDFa, but [`href` is still required](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633), and using `content` wouldn’t make sense in the first place for specifying a URI. So it should probably be:

```html
<link property="og:image" href="http://www.truewayfze.com/img/products/2.jpg" />
```

Your third error:

It means that you are using this `link` element without an `itemscope` parent. It’s a Microdata property that doesn’t "belong" anywhere. Either add a suitable parent, or use the `itemref` attribute to add it to such a parent.