# Does the commentCount property accept number in other language?

Tags: wordpress, seo, schema.org, microdata

I have a WordPress website and a plugin which converts all of English numbers to Persian ones. I can't disable the plugin because it's absolutely useful. And on the other hand, it's not possible to convert Persian numbers to English because the plugin works in lower levels.

So `commentCount` will be `<span itemprop="commentCount">۹</span>` (where ۹ equals 9).

What can I do? Does `commentCount` accept these numbers?

Answer (score -1):

you can place value in content property, like this

```
<span itemprop="commentCount" content="9">۹</span>
```

Comment: It's not something that I should enter manually. If I could enter 9, there wouldn't be any problem and I wouldn't need to start any question!

Comment: The `span` element [can’t have a `content` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) in HTML5+Microdata.