# schemas.org : SiteNavigationElement name on attribute title not text

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets

I would like to add the name base on the attribute title as there is no text displayed for the link but instead a icon using font-awesome

My link are like this :

```
<a itemprop="url" href="whatever.html">
  <i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i>
</a>
```

I need solution without javascript involve

Comment: Are you aware that your markup is not accessible? Some of your visitors might not be able to visit this link or understand what it’s about.

Comment: Yes actually in the "real" code, I use jquery ui (tooltip) so passing the mouse over it will show the "description" of the link (but agree it can be tricky for no js browser), thanks for your concern and advise will keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a itemprop="url" href="whatever.html">
  <i class="fa fa-home" title="Home"></i>
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Whatever Name You Want" />
</a>
```

(Note edited to remove incorrect alternative after below discussion).

Though as an aside, as per below conversaation, some question on whether `<i>` tag should even be used: [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Comment: Are you sure `content=` is processed by Google Structure Data Testing Tool (GSDTT)? It's valid for `RDFa` and processed by `RDFa` validators, but the last time I checked it was not processed by GSDTT.

Comment: Yup - use it myself. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: It’s [not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) in HTML5+Microdata to have a `content` attribute on the `a` or `i` element (it’s only allowed on the `meta` element).

Comment: Fair enough. I use the first format. Also is <i> even valid anymore and shouldn't it be <span>? Dunno why some frameworks insist on <i> as some validators warn on mixing presentation and content. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span

Comment: IMHO the GSDTT will not process the value for `content=` when used in `<body>`, even when using your clever work-around. Per @unor, it will be processed in `<head>`.  I'm not dismissing the validity of your structure; I'm commenting only WRT GSDTT.

Comment: Well I'm telling you GSDTT does pick it up for my site. I use it for "name" and also for "logo" (as I wanted a different logo in the info box than on my site). I recently changed the logo and, not only does this show GSDTT, but Google also picked it up and correctly displayed the new logo in the info box a few days later.

Comment: It valid w3c html5 (validator.nu) and Google snippet tester show the name as I requested

You have my respect sir thanks !