# What is the correct way of using the price schema in microdata format?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have read http://schema.org/price (Microdata example) and I want to use on one of my page.

This is what is of interest to me, I want to show price/price-range

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <!--price is 1000, a number, with locale-specific thousands separator
    and decimal mark, and the $ character is marked up with the
    machine-readable code "USD" -->
    <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span
          itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
  </div>
```

Now my page is not showing any price until some options are selected on the page, however I do have a base price (minimum) which I want to use in this case.

How and where would be the correct place to inject this base price?

I tried this on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool and it works. Not sure if this the correct way?

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <meta itemprop="price" content="2.31" />
</div>
```

[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Providing machine-readable values

This is invalid:

```html
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span>
<span itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
```

You [can’t use the `content` attribute on every element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) (it’s possible in RDFa, but not in Microdata).

You could either use the [`data` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-data-element) with its `value` attribute, or the `meta` element, e.g.:

```html
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />$
<data itemprop="price" value="1000.00">1,000.00</data>
```

#### Price range

You can use the [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) type to provide a price range. It allows you to use the [`minPrice`](http://schema.org/minPrice) and [`maxPrice`](http://schema.org/maxPrice) properties.

You can add a `PriceSpecification` with the [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification) property to the `Offer`:

```html
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
    <!-- minPrice, maxPrice, priceCurrency -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it important to add the currency character like the $ sign incase of USD? Or is that optional since you have already provided the currencyCode in the content attribute? I am using the meta tag option. @unor

Comment: @Yasser: In `<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />$`, "USD" is the value relevant for Microdata parsers. Those parsers don’t even see that there is also a "$", as it’s outside of `meta` and not part of an `itemprop` value. It’s just there for your users, otherwise they wouldn’t see which currency the price is in.

Comment: So in short, using the priceCurrency google will show appropriate $ symbol ?

Comment: @Yasser: Yes, for `priceCurrency`, Google looks for values "in three-letter ISO 4217 format" ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products#offer_properties)). What exactly they display ("$", "USD", …) is up to them, of course.